# Color glyphs from OTF font don't work in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg

1. I wanted only to test color glyphs (e.g. A, B, C, H, i, e...; see screenshot) from this OTF font: [tiny.pl/t4qfc](http://tiny.pl/t4qfc).

[image]

They don't work in Adobe Ilustrator CC. Does someone know why? E.g. in Paint.NET there are no problems with color.

[image]

This is probably a good lead: a properly functioning color font EmojiOne and Trajan have "svg" icon:

[image]

What should I do to make my font have the same status? Is there a way to convert? 
 2. Fonts EmojiOne and Trajan are colored in Illustrator, but in FontCreator are black. Why?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have [Adobe Illustrator CC 23.0.1 (64-bit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator)

Comment: Mos likely wrong font format.

Answer (score 1):

To make color fonts works you must have at least the CC 2018 AI version. 
Make sure is the right one.

[image]

*Image from [colorfonts](https://www.colorfonts.wtf/)*.

Answer (score -2):

It's solved. [required signs, required signs, required signs,]
[image: https://forum.high-logic.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8211]
[image: https://forum.high-logic.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8212]

Comment: Good that you have managed to find your answer! However, we don't do link-only answers here because they are vulnerable to link rot. You should summarize the answer if you want to avoid downvotes and deletion. Thank you!